# Can't convert division result into float or decimal type

Tags: t-sql, casting, type-conversion

I have a calculation in my t-sql code that I expect will show decimal result (with at least 2 digits after comma) 
My fields that I am using are integer type, but the calculations result is decimal

I tried using CAST as float, but won't work

```
  (COUNT(ct.[ClientFK]) / ehrprg.AnnualGoalClientsServed) AS [AnnualGoal]
 I tried:
  CAST((COUNT(ct.[ClientFK]) / ehrprg.AnnualGoalClientsServed) as float) 
                                                           AS[AnnualGoal]
```

I expect to see at lest two digits after comma -
2/50 to be 0.04  while now I am getting 0

Any advice / help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try explicitly casting the denominator to float before the quotient is taken:

```
COUNT(ct.[ClientFK]) / CAST(ehrprg.AnnualGoalClientsServed AS float) AS [AnnualGoal]
```

In the above approach, because one of the two terms in the quotient is floating point, the other term (in this case, the count) should be promoted to float as well.